# Artifacts reduction during filter cutoff change: is it possible?

Tags: filters, audio, phase

I am designing a digital sound synthesizer and prototyping it using Max. The synth in question includes a dedicated filtering module, including a bi-quadratic filter whose cutoff frequency is controlled by an ADSR segment generator.

The filter in question, unfortunately, generates some artifacts in signal when the cutoff frequency variation is high and at sample accuracy. For instance, here are some test I did using a 50Hz test sine wave and sending only the left channel to the filter (right one is the original signal):

1. cutoff change from 20kHz to 200Hz
   [image: 200Hz to 20kHz]
2. cutoff change from 200Hz to 20kHz
   [image: 20kHz to 200Hz]

   [image: 20kHz to 20Hz with sample accuracy]

Is it possible to avoid these artifacts (in particular, signal instability, phase variation) when the filter cutoff frequency, and consequently the filter coefficients, are changed? If yes, can you suggest some documentations to study more in depth possible solutions to this issue?

Comment: I'm guessing this is not caused by a phase shift but by a discontinuity of the internal state variable of the filters. Are you using Direct Form 1 ?

Comment: @Hilmar, I am currently prototyping the project using Max and in the [documentation](https://docs.cycling74.com/max8/refpages/biquad~) I don't see any information about the implementation (direct form 1 vs. 2)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's your problem. I highly recommend using Direct Form 1 for time variant IIRs. You also may have to slow down the movement of the cross over frequency which is most effectively done by putting a first order low-pass filter on the pole movements.

Comment: @Hilmar, okay, I am going to manually implement a Direct Form 1. Anyway, with regard to the cutoff frequency variation, what do you mean with "putting a first order low-pass filter *on the pole movements*"? Do you mean to low-pass literally the cutoff frequency value? Or maybe, do you refer to the filter coefficients (a1, b0, etc.)?